# Excel VBA - array used to process ranges changes the format of the cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, format

I am using an array to process the values (and texts) I have in a sheet:

```
Dim arr As Variant

arr = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
'do stuff
Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange = arr
```

However, this has a side-effect: when dumping the array back into the cells, the cells formatting is changed by Excel's default behaviour. For example, numbers stored as text which start with "0" are converted to numbers, and the "0" gets deleted. Or texts like "1-11" are converted to dates ("November 1"); and probably some others which I have not spotted yet.

If I monitor the Locals window, the strings are being preserved as strings in the array until the very moment, so it is the unloading that messes things up.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior ?

Edit: I also tried:

```
Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = arr
Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2 = arr
Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.text = arr
```

Same result for each.

Comment: Why don't you copy the formatting to an empty sheet before pasting the array and then paste (format only) back to the range?

Comment: I thought of that too, but the text is already altered; pasting the format back won't add the "0" in front of the phone number; also, when converted to date, the text is already stored as day serial number (e.g. - "1-11" is already converted into the value 42746; pasting the format won't change this back to "1-11"

Comment: Then you'll have to add an `'` up-front to all the values in the array you don't want to be recognized as numbers but wish to keep as text. For more information read this: https://superuser.com/questions/806771/why-would-all-text-columns-in-an-excel-spreadsheet-begin-with-a-leading-single-q

Comment: @Ralph :I do not know up-front which those texts are; and texts change periodically; I am talking about hundred of thousands of data-points, which are pretty random in terms of formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the valuetype option to preserve formatting etc: 11 is xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet

```
Sub CopyWithFormat()
Dim var As Variant
var = Range("A8:A11").Value(11)
Range("C8:C11").Value(11) = var
End Sub
```

But that will make it difficult to modify the values in the array.
So its probably simplest to loop the array adding '

```
Sub CopyWithFormat2()
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    var = Range("A8:A11").Value
    For j = 1 To UBound(var)
        If VarType(var(j, 1)) = vbString Then var(j, 1) = "'" & var(j, 1)
    Next j
    Range("C8:C11").Value = var
End Sub
```

Comment: The first option indeed makes it hard to process the values. The second one works only if I am dealing with strings exclusively; if I have a mix of numbers and strings, it transforms everything into strings. I need to preserve whatever format the cell had previous to loading the values into the array. I need to not change the cell formatting

Comment: When I test it the second option does not transform numbers into strings and handles a mix of numbers and strings and formats such as Currency, Text, Date, Number correctly. (OK does not copy the decimal places format for numbers but they are copied as numbers). If you continue to have numbers transformed into strings please supply some test data.

Comment: I stand corrected, you are right; I still had my .text failed attempt in the code

Answer (score 0):

Also try

```
YourRangeVariable.NumberFormat = "@"

YourRange.Value=Your Array
```

This will convert the range to text first. Works for me when using values like 01-11 and saves having to do a loop.